# SQLException during executeBatch() when I'm handling BatchUpdateException

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm having some trouble with this.

I'm trying to list some data about the queries that failed during an executeUpdate() and I have read that BatchUpdateException can be caught and then get the updateCount, that tell you which queries worked and which not, but when a query fails because a bad data conversion, it launches an SQLException and I can't catch the whole batch execution error.

The data to make the queries is fetched from a XML without any kind of validations.

Here's the code:

```
try {
    pSt_insertCabecera.executeBatch();
    } 
catch (BatchUpdateException buex){
    int[] updateCounts = buex.getUpdateCounts();  
    for (int i = 0; i < updateCounts.length; i++) {  
        if (updateCounts[i] == Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED) {  
            logger.error(nombreClase + "[ESB_P]: Ha fallado la inserción de la cabecera de pedidos: " + cabecerasAInsertar.get(i).toString());
            throw new SQLException();
        }
    }
}
```

The SQLException thrown besides the if it's because later on the code I catch it to perform a rollback.

The StackTrace looks as this:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Error al convertir una cadena de caracteres en fecha y/u hora.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatementBatch(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtBatchExecCmd.doExecute(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using SQLServer 2012.

If you need more code or information please ask.

So much thanks to everyone.

Comment: what is the exception that you get?

Comment: I get an SQLException. Thanks for replying so fast!

Comment: can you plz post up your stacktrace?

Comment: I have posted it. Thanks again.

Comment: can you post up English version plz?

Comment: @KickButtowski According to Google Translate the message in the stacktrace is "Failed to convert a string to date and / or time."

Comment: I know what is causing the Exception, but I thinked that BatchUpdateException will catch any exception in any batched query and then, I was able to know which of them caused the problem.

We need to do this to show it on the logs so we can notify to the people who generates the XML where they failed to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to recreate your issue. For a table named [Clients] with a `datetime` column named [DOB] the code

```java
String[] datesToApply = new String[] 
        {
        "1978-12-31",
        "junk",
        "1981-11-11"
        };

String sql = 
        "UPDATE Clients SET DOB=? WHERE ID=1";
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    for (String dt : datesToApply) {
        ps.setString(1, dt);
        ps.addBatch();
    }
    int[] updateCounts = null;
    try {
        updateCounts = ps.executeBatch();
    } catch (BatchUpdateException bue) {
        System.out.println("executeBatch threw BatchUpdateException: " + bue.getMessage());
        updateCounts = bue.getUpdateCounts();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        System.out.println("executeBatch threw SQLException: " + se.getMessage());
    }
    if (updateCounts != null) {
        for (int uc : updateCounts) {
            System.out.println(uc);
        }
    }
    if (!conn.getAutoCommit()) {
        conn.commit();
    }
```

throws a `SQLException` if AutoCommit is off, but it throws a `BatchUpdateException` if AutoCommit is on. Inspecting the array returned by  `.getUpdateCounts()` shows us the point in the batch at which the first failure occurred

```
executeBatch threw BatchUpdateException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
1
-3
-3
```

but it also shows that SQL Server "gives up" after the first failure. There seems to be no option to tell SQL Server to continue processing the rest of the batch (like `continueBatchOnError` for MySQL Connector/J).

In addition, since AutoCommit is "on" the updates to that point are already committed so there's no option to roll back those changes *en masse*. If you wanted the batch to be "all or nothing" you'd have to write some code to go back and reverse the changes that were successfully applied before the first failure.

(The other option, of course, is to validate the data *before* trying to put it into your database.)

Comment: Thanks Gord! Whe're assessing whether to validate the data before executing the updates or, in the cases that an SQLException is thrown, then call the same method but with AutoCommit set to "on" and make the same operations and inserting in temporary tables to get the errors. But I personally find a better choice to validate prior to inserts, but they want a quick fix, not a development...