# Why I don't get BatchUpdateException when AutoCommit is set false?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

Here in code below I get `BatchUpdateException` when  auto commit is set true and don't get when its set false and rather get a `SQLServerException` . Why? (Code is below).

Stack Traces when auto commit- true :

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'hello' to data type int.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1178)
    at dbconnect.main(dbconnect.java:48)
```

Stack Traces when auto commit = false :

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'hello' to data type int.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatementBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1299)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtBatchExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1209)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:1173)
    at dbconnect.main(dbconnect.java:48)
```

So how will I check which statement in batch caused the batch to fail when using auto-commit = false.

Microsoft SQL server is used with a Table named bot with 2 integer columns.
In code I manually make a statement in batch wrong.

```
  System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

  stmt=conn.createStatement();
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);
  PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT into bot VALUES (?,?)");

  long start,end;
  try
  {
      for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
      {
          if(i==50)
          {
              ps.setInt(1, i);
              //ps.setInt(2,i+1000);
              ps.setString(2,"hello");
              ps.addBatch();
              continue;
          }
          ps.setInt(1, i);
          ps.setInt(2,i+1000);
          ps.addBatch();
      }

      int [] result = ps.executeBatch();
      conn.commit();
  }
  catch(SQLException e)
  {
      System.out.println("Error       :");
      e.printStackTrace();

      //conn.rollback();
  }
```

Comment: Please include the actual stacktraces that you get with and without auto commit. That might help us answering your question.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : Sir I have reformed the question and provided the stack traces , can you now please release from hold ?

Comment: It looks like a bug in the driver, I am not sure if you can do anything about that other than reporting it to Microsoft (or checking if a newer version of the driver fixes it).

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978069/sqlexception-during-executebatch-when-im-handling-batchupdateexception/26993106

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : Yes the answer mentions : "throws a SQLException if AutoCommit is off, but it throws a BatchUpdateException if AutoCommit is on" but does not answer me that will I never get `BatchUpdateException` when auto commit is set false and secondly how can I then know which element of the batch led to batch failure.
Thanks for reply.